# How to get the values from a multi dimension array

Tags: php, pdo

I have a result from my db query that's look like this when dump and the query is doing what is expected, but I am have a little problem getting the array values.  I am using PHP PDO to get the result.

```
$result = $_stmt->fetchAll();
$row    = count($result);

print_r($result);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [SUM(od_price * od_qty)] => 69.85 [0] => 69.85 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [SUM(od_price * od_qty)] => 13.97 [0] => 13.97 ) 
       ) 69.8513.97
```

You can see that the result contains both an array and a string values. I have an option to get either the array or the string value.  But I would rather to get the array values since the the string values are all togather.  Can some one please explain what I am doing that's wrong in the foreach loop?

```
if($row == 2)
{               
    foreach ($result as $k) 
    {
        echo $price_1 = $k[0][0];  // expected 69.85
        echo $price_2 = $k[0][1];  // expected 13.97

    }    
    unset($k);
}
```

I need to get the expected values, but instead I am getting the string values that are all togather.

After reviewing the solutions below, here is what I came up with that works well for what I wanted.

```
        $result = $_stmt->fetchAll();
        $row    = count($result);

        $price = ""; 

        if($row == 2)
        {               
            foreach ($result as $k)
            {
                $price .= $k[0].',';
            }           
        }

        // remove the last comma
        $price = substr($price, 0, -1);

        list($totalPurchase, $shippingCost) = explode(",",$price);

        $orderAmount = $totalPurchase + $shippingCost;

        echo 'The amount is: '.$orderAmount;
```

Comment: But everything is good, you just printing values so they're appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the values in  an  array instead of  echoing  them..

```
$price_1 = array(); $price_2 = array();
if($row == 2)
{               
  foreach ($result as $k) 
  {
      array_push($price_1, $k[0][0]);  // expected 69.85
      array_push($price_2,  $k[0][1]);  // expected 13.97
  }    
 // print_r($price_1); //should store all the price1s
 // print_r($price_2); // should store all the price2s. 
 // uncomment to these lines to view array contents
}
```

Comment: Good idea, and thanks very much, but the answer is not quite what I am looking for, see the the solution appended to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Although you need to learn multidimensional arrays and foreach in general, to solve this particular task you need to use `fetchAll` with little addendum:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
foreach ($result as $k) 
{
    echo $k;
}
```

Comment: My friend, there are no one developer who know everything.  So there is no need to tell what one needs to go learn.  Your solution was not much of a help.  Developers sometimes get brain dead and start to write garbage, this can happen to the best of us.  We come to this site looking for ideas to get us to start thinking again. 
Daryl Gill provided the best idea that got my attention, please see his solution below:

Answer (score 0):

replace your loop with this:

```
foreach ($result as $k)  // iterate through all datasets
{
    echo $k[0];     // echo price of dataset
}
```

Comment: Thank for the quick response, but I tried that before and it output the string value 69.8513.97. I need to get the 69.85 and the 13.97 seperate.

Comment: @CarlBarrett To have something separated you have to output a separator as well

Answer (score 0):

It's already been answered, but i've seen in a comment that you want them seperate. So just concat a `"<br>"` or a new line space after your echo:

```
foreach ($result as $k)
{
    echo $k[0]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for kick starting my brain. I don't know why I did not think of this before...(long night)! I have done this many times in my applications, so I have appended to the question above a solution to the issue that works well.  I hope it may help someone else.